# How to use typescript with jQuery live event notation

Tags: typescript

Trying

```
$(document).on('click', '#focal-toggle', function(this: HTMLElement | HTMLElement[], e:MouseEvent) {
```

Returns an error:

```
{
    "resource": "/root/dev/work/OutrunInteractive2020/webfocusview/plain/ts/webfocusview.ts",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "2769",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "No overload matches this call.\n  The last overload gave the following error.\n    Argument of type '\"click\"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TypeEventHandlers<Document, (this: HTMLElement | HTMLElement[], e: MouseEvent) => void, Document, Document>'.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 58,
    "startColumn": 18,
    "endLineNumber": 58,
    "endColumn": 25,
    "relatedInformation": [
        {
            "startLineNumber": 7957,
            "startColumn": 5,
            "endLineNumber": 7961,
            "endColumn": 13,
            "message": "The last overload is declared here.",
            "resource": "/root/dev/work/OutrunInteractive2020/webfocusview/plain/node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts"
        }
    ]
}
```

With the message

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '"click"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TypeEventHandlers<Document, (this: HTMLElement | HTMLElement[], e: MouseEvent) => void, Document, Document>'.
```

How to solve it?

Comment: The [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler) seems to allow passing an event name, a selector, then the handler; the appropriate overload is [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts#L7740). Not sure why it's not picking it up.

Answer (score 0):

It seems one of the solutions is to pass `data` object as well:

```
$(document).on('click', '#focal-toggle', {}, function(this: HTMLElement | HTMLElement[], e:MouseEvent) {
```